# Using Selenium to access a commercial database with HTTPS security

Tags: java, search, selenium, authentication, https

Half year before. I already accessed to Factva.com(A NEWS DATABASE WITH ACCESS CONTROL) by Selenium driver,searching news automatically. However, two months ago, Factiva updates its access protocol from HTTP to HTTPS, which disables my program. 
Under HTTP, my program can switch to a new URL within the same Chrome(EVEN a new tab). I did this by using the function: chrome.get(URL) where the URL is a direct search link. I even access the new search request by this method. You know, under HTTP search, you can just combine some key words and logic operator to produce a new URL. And I use chrome.get(URL) to switch to the new search results. 
However, under HTPPS, I cannot use the above method anymore. When I use the method, Factiva shows the infos that I was in the off-login status( I should login again. Even though if I click the backforward button with my mouse, I can go back to the Factiva webpage and need not login) 
My question is: Why my old method didn't work UNDER HTTPS? How can I let Factiva know, even I use the  old method, I am already in the access and need not login again!

My old method under HTTP:

```
Class SearchTXT{

public String getSearchUrl(String keyword, String startTime, String endTime){

 String f0=”http://global.factiva.com.***.uk/zhcn/du/headlines.asp?napc=S&searchText=”

 String f2="&dateRangeMenu=custom&dateFormat=dmy&dateFrom=";

 String f4="&dateTo=";

 String f6="&sortBy=y&currentSources=";

 String f7=”Wall Street Journal”;

 String f8="&searchLanguage=custom&searchLang=EN&dedupe=0&srchuiver=2&accountid=9MEM000300&namespace=16";

 Return f0+keyword+f2+startTime+f4+endTime+f6+f7+f8;
}
}
```

AFTER login the FACTIVA database by Selenium Driver, I got a chrome with the access to FACTIVA.
Then: I use this:

```
SearchTXT st  = new SearchTXT():
String searchURL= st.geSearchUrl(“DELL”, “2011-11-10”, “2014-10-10”);
chrome.get(searchURL);
String pageSource=chrome.getPageSource();
```

Then I can use Jsoup.jar to Parser and collect the search results. 
But this method never works after the updating from HTTP to HTTPS. These days I am so annoying about this problem. 
Are there some alternative methods that can access the data under HTTPS? Maybe there are some tricks that can make my old method work again. Otherwise, I have to totally modify my whole key program and use JavascriptExecutor to deal with this problem. That means a heavy work. The worst is that the javascript code on FACTIVA website is very complicated. Some key javascript codes and functions are even not shown on the FACTIVA page source directly. 
Thanks a LOT!

Comment: Your old code relied on a non-public API. Chances are, since the API was non-public, Factiva changed it without notice.

Comment: Thanks, SiKing. I am dealing with this problem these days. Unfortunately, no solution yet.

Comment: Thanks all.I have solved the problem. Actually, there are multiply roads to the final aim. Not only one.